# try to put image for sqlite

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to put an image URL(String) into database with `SqlHelper` class. But I get some errors when I do this.I tried in many ways, but get the same error. Maybe I can't put http links in database?

Following is my DB Helper:

```
public class SqlHelper {
String title;
    String description;
    String image;
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private SqlHelper mDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBCategory";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "categoryTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    KEY_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    KEY_DESCRIPTION + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + KEY_IMAGE + TEXT_TYPE +

            " )";
    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public SqlHelper(Context c) throws SQLException {
        ourContext = c;
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SqlHelper open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }





    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public long createEntry(String title, String image,String description) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
        cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,description);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllData()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from categoryTable", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){

            HashMap<String,String>  hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("title", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(title)));
            hashmap.put("description", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(description)));
            hashmap.put("image", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(image)));


            array_list.add(hashmap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

```
11910-11929/com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table categoryTable has no column named image
09-25 15:56:46.467  11910-11929/com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting image=http://moi-pushistye-druzya.narod.ru/images/00073.jpg title=Случайный хомяк 27 description=Случайное фото случайного хомячка. Он тут — для массовости!
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table categoryTable has no column named image (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO categoryTable(image,title,description) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:520)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1523)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1395)
            at com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication.SqlHelper.createEntry(SqlHelper.java:93)
            at com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication.MainActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:159)
            at com.example.vnvbnv.myapplication.MainActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:113)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling your app and running it again?

error says "`table categoryTable has no column named image`", this situation can occur if you test your app with a DB table with lesser no of columns and introduce a column in your DB at a later point of time.

once you relaunch your app with an additional column an older version of DB is already present and onCreate of your DBHelper will not be called and the new column will not be added in your table.

uninstalling the app will clear any previous instance of DB and onCreate will be called again and you will start with a fresh table.